# Angular MatAccordian instance not accessible in component

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my Angular app, I have a MatAccordion which contains MatExpansionpanel. There is a 'expand all' button that I have in the template, that invokes the openAll() method of my component. I have used @ViewChild to access the accordion, however when the button is clicked, I get runtime error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'openAll' of undefined". I am seeing in the debug_context that while all other members are populated, the accordion is in 'undefined' state inside my component. What is the issue?

in html template,

```
<button mat-flat-button (click)="openAll()">Expand all</button>
<button mat-flat-button (click)="closeAll()">Collapse all</button>

<mat-accordion #myAccordion="matAccordion" multi="true"
```

in component,

```
import { MatAccordion } from '@angular/material';
```

```
@ViewChild('myAccordion',{static:true}) myAccordion: MatAccordion
```

```
openAll() {     
  this.myAccordion.openAll();
}
```

this above line fails, since object undefined.

I am running Angular 8.2 and material is 8.2.3

Comment: is your accordion in an if statement? if so, you need to make `static:false` and might have to put an if statement around `if(this.myAccordion) this.myAccordion.openAll();` to make sure it exists

Comment: Thanks, making static to false made it work.